# get excel file header on basis of background color pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Hi my excel file headers are random like some times headers are of 3 lines with background color of yellow and some times it's of 2 lines with bg yellow for example :

[image: 3 liner header]

or sometimes like this

[image: 2 liner header]

so from this as it's random I am thinking to make a logic on basis of color of backgroud . is there any way to achieve this in pandas python?

I am reading file like this

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name.xlsx, header=[0, 2] ,sheet_name=key)
```

so `header=[0, 2]` will be calculated on basis of background color fields

Comment: Not in pandas. Gotta use something else, like openpyxl, xlwings, etc., if you want to read the cell color.

Comment: @BigBen can you please provide some example etc ?  I have updated question

Comment: I don't think Python is going to help, but who knows, maybe someone here will jump in with some kind of innovative solution. In short, you probably need VBA for this.